Android Retrofit2 Call error when send Post request to API
Hello I start with my first Android app. I use Retrofit2 and all Get request work.
But if I have Post request I have this error:
"Unable to invoke no-args constructor for retrofit2.Call<java.lang.String[]>. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem."
Can someone help me with this?
There is Kotlin code:
fun printLabels(customerId: Int) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            apiLoading.value=true
            try {
                val barcodeLabel = ApiData(customerId.toString(), _scanData.value.map { it.barcode })
                Log.d("ApiResponse", "Starting API call")
                val call= bniApiService.printLabels(barcodeLabel)
                callToApi(
                    call,
                    onSuccess = { responseBody ->
                        Log.d("ApiResponse", "onSuccess $responseBody")
                        clearData()
                        responseBody.forEach { barcode ->
                            updateScanData(barcode)
                        }
                        _apiStatus.value = _apiStatus.value.copy(
                            isLoaded = true,
                            isError = true,
                        )
                        showErrorDialog.value = true
                    },
                    onError = {
                        Log.d("ApiResponse", "API call error")
                        clearData()
                        _apiStatus.value = _apiStatus.value.copy(
                            isLoaded = true,
                            isError = false,
                        )
                        showErrorDialog.value = true
                    }
                )


            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("ApiError", "Response- ${e.message}")
                _apiStatus.value = _apiStatus.value.copy(
                    isLoaded = false,
                    isError = true
                )
                showErrorDialog.value = true
            }
            finally {
                apiLoading.value=false
            }
        }

    }

here API service.
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(BasicAuthService())
    .build()

private val Base_URL = SharedPreferences.getBaseUrl() ?: "http://192.168.100.201:9000/"
val gson=GsonBuilder().create()
val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(Base_URL)
    .client(client)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .build()


val bniApiService = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)

interface ApiService {


    @GET("Logistic/GetCustomers")
    suspend fun getCustomers() : Array<Customer>

    @POST("Logistic/PrintLabels")
    suspend fun printLabels(@Body data : ApiData) :
            Call<List<String>>
}

When I try this API in Postman I have response 200OK with Body[]
In advance many thanks for help.
